# Debounce not working when setting state inside of it

Tags: reactjs, input, debouncing

A component that preforms autocomplete.
when typing an API request is sent so I added a debouncer.
When setting the inputValue inside the debouncer the debouncer doesn't preform.

```
const SearchComp  = ({
    autoCompleteRes,
    classes,
    currCondtionsForSelectedAction, 
    forecastForSelectedAction, 
    searchAction,
      }) => {
    const [ inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('Tel aviv')

    const changeText = (e) => {
        const searchTerm = e.target.value.trim()
        if( searchTerm === ('' || undefined)) {
            clearSearchAction()
            return
        } 
        searchAction(searchTerm)
    }

     const debounce = (func) => {
        let debouncerTimer;
        return function(e){
            setInputValue(e.target.value) // if i comment this line 
            const context = this;
            const args = arguments;
            clearTimeout(debouncerTimer);
            e.persist()
            debouncerTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                return func.apply(context,args)},1500)
        }
    }

    const onClickedRes = (selected) => {
        setInputValue(`${selected.LocalizedName}, ${selected.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName} ${selected.Country.LocalizedName}`)
        forecastForSelectedAction(selected);
        currCondtionsForSelectedAction(selected);
    }

    return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <div className={classes.inputWrapper}>

                    <input type="text" className={classes.inputStyle} name="firstname" 
                        value={inputValue} // and comment this line the debouncer works
                        onChange={debounce(changeText)} 
                    />
                    <div className={classes.dropDownContent}>
                      {autoCompleteRes.map(item => (
                          <div 
                            key={item.Key} 
                            className={classes.autoCompleteSingleRes} 
                            onClick={() =>  onClickedRes(item) }
                          >
                             {`${item.LocalizedName}, ${item.AdministrativeArea.LocalizedName} ${item.Country.LocalizedName}`}
                         </div>))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
;}
```

Instead of one call to the changeText function I call every keyboard stroke.

not sure what's going on and how to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

By having your debounce function inside of your Functional Component, it is recreating the function on every render (each keystroke would cause a re-render), and applying the newly created `debounce` function to your `changeText`.

There are a couple of approaches you could take here:

1) Move the `debounce` function outside of your component so it is idempotent between renders. This means you put `setInputValue` and such in to the `func` argument you pass to your debounce, as they are now not in scope.

2) Wrap your `debounce` function in a `React.useCallback` which will memoize the `debounce` so it does not change between renders unless the dependencies it relies upon change (`setinputValue`).

Comment: 1) will not pass the correct value to the input field, since the `func` is called inside `setTimeout` only after the `setTimeout` is finished will `setInputValue` be called
------------------------------------------------------------------------

2) I tried using it but maybe i'm missing something. since it didn't have any effect.
   `useCallback((func) => { 
...
 debouncerTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                return func.apply(context,args)},1500)
        }
    }, [])`